# How to change variables with in a string into a Map

Tags: groovy

I have let's say 100 variables in a string , my requirement is to automatically create a `Map` out of the string:

```
String str = "$$test$$ $$test2$$ $$test$$ $$test3$$"
```

Expected Result:

```
["test":test, "test2":test2, "test3":test3];
```

EDIT (for dsharew)
This is the last version of my code

```
def list = queryText.findAll(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/)

def map = [:]
list.each{
log.debug(it)
    it = it.replace("\$\$", "")
log.debug(it)
    map.putAt(it, it)
}

log.debug(list)
log.debug(map)
queryText = queryText.replaceAll(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/) { k -> map[k[1]] ?: k[0] }
log.debug(queryText)
```

And the logs print the following result:

```
$$test$$
test
$$test2$$
test2
$$test$$
test
$$test3$$
test3
[$$test$$, $$test2$$, $$test$$, $$test3$$]
{test=test, test2=test2, test3=test3}
test test2 test test3
```

Comment: Do you really have hundred variables? what is your use case?

Comment: I have a script unit in Webratio which returns all the placeholders of hundreds of RTF templates and those are given as inputs in this other script which must do the mapping like I've shown

Comment: Does the variables have sequence its name?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you asked, the variable always has the name of the placeholder, for example if I have `$$NAME$$` in my template, I will need `["NAME":NAME]` in my `Map`

Comment: have you tried my suggestion ?

Comment: You will need to know the names of the variables to put them in to a map.  As it stands, I don't believe you have a mechanism for this (or any decent option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
def queryText = "\$\$test\$\$ \$\$test2\$\$ \$\$test\$\$ \$\$test3\$\$"
toMap(queryText.findAll(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/));

def toMap(list){
    def map = [:]
    list.each{
        it = it.replace("\$\$", "")
        map.putAt(it, it)
    };
    println map;
    return map;

}
```

Comment: My last step is the following: 
`queryText = queryText.replaceAll(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/) { k -> map[k[1]] ?: k[0] }` so how can I adapt your solution?

Comment: what is this? queryText?

Comment: just a String such as "$$test1$$ contains test1"

Comment: ok can you post the final result of the value of queryText so I can change my solution for you

Comment: can you use different delimter because ```$``` sign has a special meaning in groovy? can you use comma?

Comment: Updated my answer per your comments

Comment: I actually can't. A simple String could be `queryText = "This is a $$test$$ and this is a $$test2$$"`

Comment: I personally am using `$$test$$ $$test2$$ $$test$$ $$test3$$ test test2 test test3` as my test String. The closest result to what i need is `Map map = ["test":test, "test2":test2, "test3":test3];

queryText = queryText.replaceAll(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/) { k -> map[k[1]] ?: k[0] }` which prints `IT WORKS IT DOES test test2 test test3` (`test="IT"; test2="WORKS"; test3="DOES"`)

Comment: doesn't work, the first replace replaces all my placeholders. Can you use `queryText = "$$test$$ HELLO $$test2$$ WORLD $$test$$" ` ?

Comment: I know but have you tested it, the answer works for the example

Comment: Yes I've tested it, the problem is that the map should be `[test:valueof(test)]` so the problem is accessing the value of the variable with the name given as a String

Comment: But you said the value with be the variable name itself? good luck

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear enough, sorry, thanks for your huge help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142139/discussion-between-dsharew-and-gila3).

Answer (score 1):

Following @dsharew answer, I've reduced it a little bit more:

```
​def queryText = "\$\$test\$\$ \$\$test2\$\$ \$\$test\$\$ \$\$test3\$\$"    

def resultMap = queryText
  .findAll(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/)
  .collectEntries { String next ->         
    [next.replace("\$\$", "")] * 2                    
  }
```

- `collectEntries` can be used to return a map from a collection if it returns a map or a tuple for every entry in the collection.
- If you multiply a list by `n`, you are creating a bigger list with `n` times its content

BTW cool problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

```
String str = '$$test$$ $$test2$$ $$test$$ $$test3$$'
str.replaceAll('\\$\\$', '').split(' ').collectEntries { [(it):it] }
```

Comment: This code is ok, but doesn't work for example with: ​`String str = '$$test$$ $$test2$$ $$test$$ $$test3$$ $$t'` even if that's a very remote case. Thanks for your time anyways! May be helpful to somebody :)

Comment: You should add that as your example input and describe how partial words are handled